# DBMS Relational Schema Mapping

Tags: mapping, schema, entity-relationship, relational

I would like to know how to map ER into a relational schema when we have following situation given

**1. One to Many Relationships with one side total participation**

**2. Many to Many Relationship with both side Total**

**3. When we have a Weak entity based relationship with identifying relation and without a** **identifying relationship.**

**4. When we have One to One relationship with a descriptive attribute.**

**5. Weak entities are always having total participation and many cardinality?**

Also i would like to know whether it's possible to have such situations exist in reality. I don't have that much of knowledge about these mapping methods there for i really appreciate if someone can point me out these situations using simple examples.

Thank you

Comment: This question would be more appropriate in dba.stackexchange.com. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic